Why color doesn't set to red?
Why doesn't change color to red, when I set my color again for its respective object?
First, I set the color value so result is in green color and then when instantiating my object I set it to be red but it doesn't seem to apply...
if my code is wrong so please tell me what i need to do?
(maybe it's a stupid question but I'm starting in Java and I'm putting into practice what I learned watching some tutorials xd)
My code and JFrame result
public class Estatico extends JFrame{
     private JLabel lbl1, lbl2, lbl3;
     private Color backgroundColor;
     private int xPosition = 20;
     
     public Estatico() {
         setBounds(0, 0, 450, 300);
         setLayout(null);
         setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         
         backgroundColor = new Color(0, 255, 0);
         
         lbl1 = new JLabel("Label1");
         lbl1.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 20);
         lbl1.setOpaque(true);
         lbl1.setBackground(backgroundColor);
         add(lbl1);
         
         lbl2 = new JLabel("Label2");
         lbl2.setBounds(120, 20, 50, 20);
         lbl2.setOpaque(true);
         lbl2.setBackground(backgroundColor);
         add(lbl2);
         
         lbl3 = new JLabel("Label3");
         lbl3.setBounds(220, 20, 50, 20);
         lbl3.setOpaque(true);
         lbl3.setBackground(backgroundColor);
         add(lbl3);  
     }
     
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Estatico objeto1 = new Estatico();
         objeto1.backgroundColor = new Color(255, 0, 0);             
         objeto1.setVisible(true);
     }
 }


basically when you call setColor(backgroundColor), it is NOT setting the color to the variable, but to the value (content) of the variable; the color is NOT  bound to the variable; so if the value of the variable is changed after the setColor() call, it will NOT change the displayed color. That is one reason to not change the variable directly, but by calling a setter method (e.g. setBackgroundColor() in Estatico) - that method would call setBackground() for all relevant components

In the main method, you try to change the backgroundColor to red after creating an instance of Estatico with new Color(255, 0, 0). But this change isn't affecting the labels (lbl1, lbl2, lbl3) because their background color was already set in the constructor ( Estatico() ), and changing the backgroundColor variable afterwards doesn't update the labels' background colors.
To fix this maybe try to pass backgroundColor over with the constructor
public class Estatico extends JFrame {
    ...

    public Estatico(Color bgColor) {
        //now use bgColor
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Estatico objeto1 = new Estatico(new Color(255, 0, 0));
        ...
    }
}

